# Two threads not multi-threading in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

My code:

```
  Test.java

   public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Account acc = new Account();

    Thread1 t1 = new Thread1(acc);
    Thread2 t2 = new Thread2(acc);
    Thread t = new Thread(t2);


    t1.start();
    t.start();



        /*
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            System.out.println("Main Thread : "+i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        */


}

}
```

Thread1.java

```
public class Thread1 extends Thread {

Account acc;

public Thread1(Account acc){
    super();
    this.acc=acc;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        acc.withdraw(100);
    }

}

}
```

Thread2.java

```
public class Thread2 implements Runnable {

Account acc;

public Thread2(Account acc){
    super();
    this.acc=acc;
}

public void run() {

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        acc.deposit(100);
    }

}
}
```

Account.java

```
public class Account {

volatile int balance = 500;

public synchronized void withdraw(int amount){
    try {
        if(balance<=0){
            wait();
        }

        balance=balance-amount;
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("Withdraw : "+balance);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public synchronized void deposit(int amount){
    try {
        balance = balance+amount;
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("Deposit : "+balance);

        notify();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}

OUTPUT:
Withdraw : 400
Withdraw : 300
Withdraw : 200
Withdraw : 100
Withdraw : 0
Deposit : 100
Deposit : 200
Deposit : 300
Deposit : 400
Deposit : 500
```

What i am trying to achieve in this code is MUltithreading.
I want thread1 and thread2 running simultaniusly as you can see in the output it is not being run that way.

It first runs all withdraw and then deposit.
I want both withdraw and deposit to run at the same time in random fashion.
It is running serially when it should not have been.
Please let me know where i have gone wrong in my code.

Comment: You should debug your code yourself first. And if you really can't figure it out you need to create a [mcve], this is way too much code. Also in the process of creating a [mcve] you will often figure out your mistake yourself

Comment: They're threads. They execute independently unless you synchronize their actions in some way. `Thread.sleep()` is a code smell that allows race conditions. Consider using an [Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) and feeding it withdrawal and deposit tasks in the desired order. Otherwise, define the order you want, and enforce it with the synchronization mechanisms in package `java.util.concurrent`. As a side note, consider not misleadingly naming a Runnable as `Thread2`, when it's not a thread.

Comment: Okay Thanks @UnholySheep

Comment: thanks @AndyThomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your code is running in parallel.

There are so few iterations in view that I don't think you would practically hit any race conditions. I suggest you put random sleeps in your code and perhaps a few locks to provoke artificial contention.

Also, consider naming your threads and connecting the `jvisualvm` application to inspect your running threads.

Comment: Thanks so much @Sam

Answer (score 0):

The running sequences of threads cannot be controlled.Scheduler schedules the thread and they run.However we can put sleep sequences while thread is running.It will put thread from Running to Ready state and scheduler may schedule another thread in meantime.
    `Thread.sleep(300)//300 is time in milliseconds`

Comment: The OP's code is already using `Thread.sleep()`. Using `Thread.sleep()` is usually a code smell, because it does not guarantee any order of execution among multiple independent threads.